# Get the private key of digital signature in Java

Tags: java, digital-signature, p2p

I am trying to make my first P2P software and I will use digital signature for identifying users. I followed [this tutorial on Oracle.com](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/apisign/gensig.html). It only says how to get the public key, but not how to get the private key.

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
keyGen.initialize(1024, random);
KeyPair pair = keyGen.generateKeyPair();
PrivateKey priv = pair.getPrivate(); //It's not possible to print this.
PublicKey pub = pair.getPublic(); //It's possible to print this.
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Both `PrivateKey` and `PublicKey` have the same methods (both implement the `Key` interface). What do you mean by "print" they key? Generally you would add them to a `KeyStore` or write the bytes out to disk as a file.

Comment: This question would be better if you'd provided the `println` statements and the `keyGen` variable wasn't declared / instantiated either.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the private key secure. Printing it out (and storing the values in a string in general) is not secure. Imagine that you mistakenly perform a `toString()` on the private key and you get the private key in your log files. That would certainly not be a good idea.

As long as you're using the SunRSA provider (and most other providers that store the keys *in your computer's unprotected memory*) it's easy to print out the values though, just cast to `RSAPrivateKey` or (if you need all of the values) `RSAPrivateCrtKey` and retrieve the integers yourself:

```
RSAPrivateCrtKey asCrt = (RSAPrivateCrtKey) priv;
System.out.printf("%s, %d bits%n", asCrt.getAlgorithm(), asCrt.getModulus().bitLength());
System.out.printf("  modulus: %d%n", asCrt.getModulus());
System.out.printf("  private exponent: %d%n", asCrt.getPrivateExponent());
```

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to also convert a string (that is a private key) to PrivateKey variable? Do you know any good book about java security?

Comment: Of course. You first parse the string into `BigInteger` values. Then you convert then into RSA key specifications and put those into an `"RSA"` `KeyFactory`.